# set a different font for the fragments of a String

Tags: android, string, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I want to set a different font for the fragments of a String.

The program works, but it is not formatted String

Please help

this is my code:

```
...
    // List view
    private ListView lista;    
    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;     
    // Search EditText
    EditText poleSearch;   
    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;
...
List<String> customers = new ArrayList<String>();

        if(myCursor.getCount()!=0){
            myCursor.moveToFirst();         
            do{
                String myStringCode = "<big> "+myCursor.getString(0)+" </big> \n <small> Adres: "+myCursor.getString(1)+" </small>";
                Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(myStringCode);          
                customers.add( spanned.toString());

            }while(myCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        }
...

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row_client, R.id.tvRC2, customers);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);  
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `break` tag to insert a newline character when formatting a String using Html. so replace `/n` with `<br></br>`

```
String myStringCode = "<big> "+myCursor.getString(0)+" </big> <br></br> <small> Adres: "+myCursor.getString(1)+" </small>";
```

Comment: changed to /n to <br></br>, but there is no effect :/

Comment: font size: <big>myCursor.getString(0)</big>+<small>myCursor.getString(1)</small>

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SpannableString and set span of different fonts for different parts of the string

```
TypefaceSpan ts=new TypefaceSpan("<your font>");
    SpannableString s=new SpannableString("");
    s.setSpan(ts, 0, 3, 0);
```